# Get input type from an ElementHandle within page.$$('input')

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

I've set up puppeteer to go through all  tags and fill them with random stuff (or just blabla in the code below).

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async ()=> {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields')
//^ Not my page, for test purposes only ^
const inputs = await page.$$('input');
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length ; i++) {
  const curren = inputs[i];
  await curren.type('blablabla');
  //Find out curren's input type here
}
await page.screenshot({path: 'test.png'});
await browser.close();
})
();
```

Now, I need to know what is the **type** of the input tag: text, password, reset, etc.

With `console.log(await curren.getProperty('type'))`, it shows a lot of stuff, plus what I actually need, under `_client: CDPSession { _remoteObject: { type: 'string', value: 'reset' } }`. How to I actually get that value within remoteObject alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getProperty` will return a `JSHandle`. If you need the value of that `JSHandle` you can call `jsonValue()`:

```
const type = await (await curren.getProperty('type')).jsonValue();
```

If you want to do that in one call, you can use evaluate:

```
const type = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('type'), current);
```